# How to power a DC motor using the output of a driver IC

Tags: driver, motor-controller

I am a hobbyist new to electronics, trying to build a water level indicator (and controller) for my water tank. I built a circuit (like the image below) which uses an [ULN2003](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uln2003.pdf) IC to turn on the LEDs according to the water level.

[image: Image showing circuit]

However, to turn off the water pump, I am thinking to make a linear actuator which works like a fingerbot. For this, first I should be able to run a DC motor when the level reaches M1 (hence when pin 10 is grounded).

I built the circuit and everything (LEDs and buzzer) works fine, but I can't find a way to power the DC motor.

If I place a DC motor in the place of the buzzer in the diagram, the DC motor won't run, I am not sure about the reason, but I think the current is too low for the motor to work.

Now how do I take the signal from water level reaching M1 and turn a motor when it does?

**Edit**

Responding to one of the comments, as a hobbyist (who is curious to learn about electronics) and considering reliability of my circuit, I decided to go for the fingerbot control instead of controlling the pump directly.

**Update**

Motor specs:

Operating Voltage: 4.5V to 9V,
Recommended/Rated Voltage: 6V,
Current at No load: 70mA (max)
No-load Speed: 9000 rpm,
Loaded current: 250mA (approx),
Rated Load: 10g*cm

Comment: I think it would be easier to control the pump directly, rather than using a linear actuator to operate a switch to control the motor.  In any case, you will have to add power transistors capable of handling the motor current.  There should be many questions on here with suggested circuits.

Answer (score 0):

First you must pick the DC motor you are going to drive, and assuming that you want to drive an actuator to turn a switch on and off, you need something like an stepper motor.

Depending on the force needed to push the botton you pick the stepper, and depending on the stepper you pick an IC for driving the stepper, for instance the [STSPIN220](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stspin220.pdf).

Depending on the motor you need to make sure you have a suitable power source: enough current, and proper voltage.

To control the IC inputs (MODE bits in this example), you should create your own digital logic with logic gates, or you can use a microcontroller.

[image]

Comment: ...with logic gates or a CPLD or use a microcontroller...

Comment: How do I take the logic from the pin 10 of ULN2003 (as in the diagram) to power the motor? I am sorry if the question seems vague, but it would be helpful if you provide some references where I can get to learn such things.